# Selenium firefox profile not being set correctly

Tags: firefox, selenium

I have the following code snippet.  I want pdf files to be automatically saved to the directory.

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['browser.download.dir'] = "//Users/mmuenster/www/pc_interface/pdf_downloads"
profile['browser.download.folderList'] = 2
profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = 'application/pdf'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile
driver.manage.window.maximize
```

However, though the "about:config" in Firefox shows this option being set, when I got to preferences and applications in Firefox, pdfs are set to "Preview in Firefox".

Any ideas what is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I discovered the problem.  I upgraded to Firefox 19 which has the pdfjs add-on built in.  The solution was to add the following

```
profile['pdfjs.disabled'] = true
```

This worked!

Comment: From searching around, I also came upon this solution as well. I am clicking on a link ( <a> tag) with the download attribute set. This bypasses the viewer even if is enabled and forces the download dialog to popup. I thought setting browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk would avoid the dialog, but it kept popping up. Only after disabling the pdf viewers was the dialog averted. A frustrating bug.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Python solution I use, now with the above suggested pdfjs diable.

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "~/somewhere/here/")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf")
fp.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
fp.update_preferences()
```